# Is there a better way to grant access to AWS Lambda so that it can call AWS Simple Email Service?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am using AWS Simple Email Service within AWS Lambda functions (written in Nodejs) to send emails to users.

My only option is to use Service based approach, where I have used the following Statement for AWS Lambda function to allow it to use SES service, using the following (from .yml file):

```
...    
- Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - ses:SendEmail
            - ses:SendRawEmail
          Resource:
            - "*"
...
```

I am curious to know if there is a better way to use something more specific rather than using.

```
Resource: 
    - "*"
```

I will have multiple domains under verified entities, and the list will keep changing time to time.

Also, are there any downsides of using Resource: -"*" in this particular case?

Any thoughts :)

Comment: you may try to tag the SES resources and then use a condition operator to allow resources with  the specific tags

Comment: You can restrict the FROM address. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonses.html#amazonses-ses_FromAddress

Comment: Maybe create a seperate execution role for the lambda and update that as needed.  That way, you dont have to redeploy the lambda when your resource list changes.